# How to get user's phone number from python social auth(google-oauth2)

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I use python social auth and django rest framework.
I want to fetch the user phone number.

Settings

```
 SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = config('GOOGLE_ID')
    SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = config('GOOGLE_SECRET')
    SOCIAL_AUTH_RAISE_EXCEPTIONS = False
    SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.TransUser'
    SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_USER_FIELDS = ['email', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'phone_number']
    SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read',
        'profile',
        'email',
    
    ]
```

Ouput

```
{'access_token': 'xxxxxxxx',
 'email': 'xxxxxxxx,
 'email_verified': True,
 'expires_in': 3582,
 'family_name': 'xxxxxxx',
 'given_name': 'xxxxx',
 'id_token': 'xxxxxx',
 'locale': 'es',
 'name': 'xxxxxxx',
 'picture': 'xxxxx',
 'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email '
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read '
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid',
 'sub': 'xxxxxx',
 'token_type': 'Bearer'}
```

but never phone number.

I use user's phone number to registration it.
I activated people APi in google console.

Thx you